# DirectorySearcher Filter by Properties?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry, directorysearcher

I want to be able to get all "owners" for a Distribution Group.  This includes the Group attribute named `managedBy` as well as the Exchange attribute `msExchCoManagedByLink` which is a collection of user DNs.  I am able to set a DirectorySearcher filter using `managedBy` with no problem but I can find no documentation on how to add a filter that will work on attributes that are collections.

Here's the filter I have right now:

```
$"(&(objectClass=group)(|(grouptype=8)(grouptype=4)(grouptype=2))(|({GroupProperty.ManagedBy}={userDn})({GroupProperty.CoManagedBy}=*{userDn}*)))";
```

`userDn` is a parameter and is passed in.

`GroupProperty.ManagedBy` is simply the "managedBy" string.

`GroupProperty.CoManagedBy` is simply the string "msExchCoManagedByLink"

I want to avoid having to write a "groups cache" that load all the groups and the two property fields mentioned (aggregating the owner and co-owners into a single list) but right now I can find no decent way around this hack.

So... anyone know how to filter by a collection field like `msExchCoManagedByLink`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use filter like (msExchCoManagedByLink:=CN=myuser,OU=Test,DC=contoso,DC=com), for multi valued attribute - added colon (msExchCoManagedByLink:=). However this filter returns all groups, where "my user" is specified in msExchCoManagedByLink attribute. If you need to return owners of the group, you have to bind to the group and query for its managedBy\msExchCoManagedByLink attributes, then parse the result. if you need need to find all groups which have attribute msExchCoManagedByLink set (not empty), specify (msExchCoManagedByLink=*) in the filter

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I too want a script/program to get ALL owners for group/DL, so the first paragraph sounded like what I'm trying to do.  After that, though, your question seems to me to split off and ask about trying to *filter* by who can edit the group.  In my case, I don't want to filter anything, just return all the owners for a give group name. Did you ever get that working?

Comment: Yes. I did. Let me find a good way to post it here.

Comment: [GitHub Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f047e8fdedefaae5408b5a7ad53a7cd9)

Comment: That Gist above has a ton of stuff in it you might find useful. Look at the GetOwners method as well as its caller and you'll have everything you want.